# Name change with Australian passport and UK BRP

Tags: visas, uk, australian-citizens

I am an Australian citizen working in the UK on a Tier 2 visa,
I have legally changed my name in the UK (by stat dec) and Australia (via updated birth certificate).

Next week I will be updating it on my passport.
I haven't yet applied to change my Biometric Residence Permit (BRP), since I assume it needs to agree with my passport.

My new passport will probably take at least 6 weeks to arrive. Meanwhile I will still have my old one and I know I can travel on that.
My new BRP will take unknown time to arrive; i am not sure if they will take my old one away when I ask for a new one, or just tell me to destroy my old one once the new one arrives.
I have a lot of travel to do over the next few months, and so don't want to be stuck.
(In general as a non-citizen I am terrified of not having the ability to leave and enter the country at will)

Should I apply for a new BRP around the same time I submit my new passport application paperwork next week?
Or should I hold off until i have the new passport in my hands?

Answer (score 4):

According to https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/biometric-residence-permits-overseas-applicant-and-sponsor-information/biometric-residence-permits-overseas-applicant-and-sponsor-information-accessible-version you have three months to notify changes to your personal details on your biometric residence permit

> You must tell us as soon as you can if:
>
> - you change your name (for example, because of marriage or by deed poll);
> - you change your gender, legally or permanently;
> - you change your nationality; or
> - your facial appearance changes significantly.
>
> If you change any personal details listed above or any details shown on your biometric residence permit, you must apply for a new permit within three months, by making an application for transfer of conditions (TOC) or no time limit (NTL). You can download the application forms and guidance at [Transfer Visa](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa)

If you do not do this, you may have to pay a financial penalty of up to £1,000 or your permission to stay may be shortened.